How to find the prerequisite from list based on target list
GNU Make 3.80 on Windows 11
I have a list of files and a list of destinations. I need to write a rule that will copy each file to its corresponding destination (in a specified subdirectory). Note, there is no pattern to the filenames, they are manually maintained lists; the only requirement is that the files (in ADDFILES) exist.
Essentially, something like this (extra spacing for visual clarity):
ADDFILES = Makefile  ../Docs/test.log  images/screen.jpg
ASFILES  = Makefile  test.log          images/screen.jpg
DESTDIR  = Others/

$(addprefix $(DESTDIR),$(ASFILES)): $(ADDFILES)
    copy $< $@

Obviously, that rule does not work.
The results should be
copy Makefile          Others/Makefile
copy ../Docs/test.log  Others/test.log
copy images/screen.jpg Others/images/screen.jpg

I tried with no prerequisite and with $(ADDFILES) as the prerequisite.
With the prerequisite ($ADDFILES), $< is always the first word in the list (lower-cased for some reason). Without a prerequisite, $< is blank.
I am not terribly fluent in make. I have been searching, and coming close, but I can't get this to work. Is it possible at all? Remember, I am running on Windows, with no *nix-type shell available.
Edit to Add
What I'm looking for is some way to interpret ADDFILES and ASFILES (from the example above) as if it were:
Others/Makefile: Makefile
    copy $< $@

Others/test.log: ../Docs/test.log
    copy $< $@

Others/images/screen.job: images.screen.jpg
    copy $< $@


$< means the first prerequisite of the rule.  Moreover, a rule with multiple targets expresses that each of those targets depends on all the specified prerequisites, which seems not to be what you mean.

You could have a POSIX shell availble.  MSYS2 provides that and many other conventional UNIX tools for Windows.  You could also have a less crusty version of make.  v3.80 is around 20 years old now.

@JohnBollinger: yeah, I'm working with what I have, but I may have to install something to get where I want. Frankly, I would rather use Linux all the way.

make has only a very weak sense of lists, and I don't know any good way in make itself to associate elements of one list with elements of another by index.  If you were using bash for the shell with which to run recipes then you could do it there.  I'm not optimistic about doing that in CMD.EXE but PowerShell is much more capable, and I bet that you could do it there, though I can't suggest details.  You should be able to use PS to run your recipes by setting the SHELL variable appropriately in your makefile, but be aware that it will apply to all your recipes.

Sorry, but with that ancient and decrepit version of GNU Make you are totally SOL.  GNU Make 3.80 was released 22 years ago.  Some newer versions of GNU Make introduce features which would make this possible.

What you're describing sounds like a pattern rule. According to the docs, those existed in version 3.80, so this should be possible. Here are the 3.80 docs: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.80/html_node/make_105.html#SEC109

Thanks to everyone who looked and offered suggestions. I was able to almost solve it with what I had. But I kept having trouble with the directory separators. Make will take them either way (forward or backward); and Windows will, to a degree. But on the Windows command line, a forward-slash is considered a switch by most (all?) commands.
The working Windows solution (with make 3.8) required writing to a file and including that file. There may still be issues in this example because I used forward-slash in the file names inside the variables. I got tired of trying to escape and transpose them. But it looked like this.
ADDFILES = Makefile  ../Docs/test.log  images/screen.jpg
ASFILES  = Makefile  test.log          images/screen.jpg
DESTDIR  = Others/

ADDJOIN := $(join $(addprefix $(DESTDIR),$(ASFILES)),$(addprefix #,$(ADDFILES)))

INCLMK := _addfiles_.mk

# Build make file for ADDFILES
$(shell rm $(INCLMK);\
    for var in $(ADDJOIN); \
    do readarray -td# parts <<<"$${var}#"; \
    echo "$${parts[0]}: $${parts[1]}"; \
    echo "  mkdir -p $$(dirname $${parts[0]})";\
    echo "  cp $${parts[1]} $${parts[0]}"; \
    echo; \
    done >$(INCLMK))

include $(INCLMK)

So, I ended up installing cygwin and using bash. This also got me a newer GNU make (4.4.1). So, I was able to accomplish this without the extra makefile; the rules become a part of the current invocation. Note: the generated rules still have the requirement that the recipe start with a TAB character.
ADDFILES = splitpair.sh        project.xml
ASFILES  = Others/splitpair.sh Others/xml/project.xml

ADDJOIN := $(join $(ASFILES),$(addprefix ^,$(ADDFILES)))

define addRule 
$1: $2
    mkdir -p `dirname $1`
    cp $2 $1

endef

$(foreach pair,$(ADDJOIN),\
    $(eval \
        $(call \
            addRule,\
            $(firstword $(subst ^, ,$(pair))),\
            $(lastword $(subst ^, ,$(pair))))))

I used a single line but show it split here for ease of reading. Note that there is a space before the backslash in some of those lines (after eval and after call; nowhere else).
ADDFILES is a list of existing files that are to be copied to a specific directory (Others/).
ASFILES is a corresponding list of (target) files - what I want to copy to
ADDJOIN joins the two lists on a word-by-word basis - that is, the first word from ASFILES (Others/splitpair.sh) is concatenated with the first word from ADDFILES (splitpair.sh). But while doing that, I added a delimiter (the caret ^) so I can split them later. Then the second word from each list are combined (with the caret). The combinations are separated by a space; so the combined entries become words. From the above, ADDJOIN will look like this:
Others/splitpair.sh^splitpair.sh Others/xml/project.xml^project.xml

The foreach command walks this list. Each word (we have two) in ADDJOIN, is assigned (in turn) to the variable pair. For each pair, we use eval (because without it we loose the formatting of addRule) to call addRule (as if it were a function) passing in two arguments.
The first argument - $(firstword $(subst ^, ,$(pair))) - substitues a space for the caret in pair causing it to become two words; then takes the firstword of that (my target).
The second argument - $(lastword $(subst ^, ,$(pair))) - does the same substitution but takes the lastword (my preprequisite).
addRule accepts these two arguments and creates the rule.
I have this working now in the big Makefile I was working on. Thank you, again, for all the suggestions. I hope this explanation helps someone else in the future.

Related: stackoverflow.com/questions/78295071/how-to-instruct-make-to-copy-the-i-th-file-of-a-list-to-the-i-th-path-of-another.

For more "traditional" approach - that does not use eval of generated rules, consider using bash snippet to perform the copy.
The basic idea is to use "conditional" copy, where files are only copied IFF they are NEWER than the destination. The cp -u is one simple option (rsync can also be used if you your cp is old). Following bash snippet should do the trick:
DIRS=$(sort $(addprefix ${DESTDIR}/, $(dir $(ASFILES))))

$(DIRS): Makefile
        mkdir -p $@ && touch $@

update: SHELL=bash
update: $(DIRS)
update: $(ADDFILES)
        FROM=($(ADDFILES)) ; TO=($(ASFILES)) ; N=$(words $(ADDFILES)) ; for ((i=0 ; i<$$N ; i++)) ; do [[ "$(DESTDIR)/$${TO[i]}" -nt "$${FROM[i]}" ]] || sh -cx "cp -u $${FROM[i]} $(DESTDIR)/$${TO[i]}" ; done


Another alternative is to use helper script to make it easier to maintain (simpler quoting, indentation, comments, ...). Note: I did not actually tried the below.
Makefile:
update:
    update_files '$(ADDFILES)' '$(ASFILES)', '$(DEST)'

Bash Helper: update_files
#! /bin/bash
FROM=($1)
TO=$($2)
DEST=$3
N=${#SRC[*]}
for ((i=0 ; i<N ; i++))
do
    FROM_FILE=$TO[i]
    TO_FILE=$DEST/${TO[i]}
    if [[ "$TO_FILE" -nt "$FROM_FILE" ]] || sh -cx "cp -u "$FROM_FILE" "$TO_FILE"
done

